# I cannot view the html content using ng-route directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, parse-platform

I am trying to route my navbar using angular js but the content in that HTML file is not displaying, I don't know what is the problem.

here is my register page in this register and login functionality is there on angularjs parse

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AuthApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>
<!-- start: CSS -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/signuplogintoggle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link  href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="css/sidebarnav.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- end: CSS -->

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>EPPF</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div ng-hide="currentUser">

      <form ng-show="scenario == 'Sign up'"  class="form-signin" role="form">

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading text-center">EPPF</h2>
        Email: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" class="form-control" /><br />
        Username: <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" ng-model="user.password"  class="form-control"/><br />
        <button ng-click="signUp(user)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign up</button>
        </br>
        <a href="#" ng-click='scenario="Log in"'><p class="text-center">Login</p></a>
      </div>
      </form>

    <form ng-show="scenario == 'Log in'" class="form-signin" role="form">
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

      Username: <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control" role="form"/><br />
      Password: <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control" role="form" /><br />
      <button ng-click="logIn(user)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>
    </br>
     <a href="#" ng-click='scenario="Sign up"'><p class="text-center">Sign up</p></a>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="currentUser">

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="" ng-controller = "MainCtrl">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="menu">
                      <a ng-click="setRoute('home')" class="btn">Home</a>
                      <a ng-click="setRoute('about')" class="btn" >About</a>
                      <a ng-click="setRoute('dashboard')" class="btn">dashboard</a>
                    </div>
                      <div class="ng-view">
                      </div>
              </div>

        </div>

        <button ng-click="logOut(user)" class="logout">Log out</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      Parse.initialize("34olOarYIJtsSy1YcuCdR4RFBPzKthQfAyotWjXP", "vvoqLVt7kMDwuxYliMuOJthEpMvRA3PVFdxC5izY");

      angular.module('AuthApp', [])
      .run(['$rootScope', function($scope) {
      $scope.scenario = 'Sign up';
      $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();

      $scope.signUp = function(form) {
        var user = new Parse.User();
        user.set("email", form.email);
        user.set("username", form.username);
        user.set("password", form.password);

        user.signUp(null, {
          success: function(user) {
            $scope.currentUser = user;
            $scope.$apply();
          },
          error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Unable to sign up:  " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });
      };

      $scope.logIn = function(form) {
        Parse.User.logIn(form.username, form.password, {
          success: function(user) {
            $scope.currentUser = user;
            $scope.$apply();
          },
          error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Unable to log in: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });
      };

      $scope.logOut = function(form) {
        Parse.User.logOut();
        $scope.currentUser = null;
      };
      }]);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my register page and angular js code is

```
angular.module('AuthApp',[]).
    config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.
        when('/about', {template:'partials/about.html'}).
        when('/dashboard', {template:'partials/dashboard.html'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/home',template:'partials/home.html'})
    });
function MainCtrl($scope,$location) {
  $scope.setRoute = function(route){
    $location.path(route);
  }
}
```

I don't know what is the problem I cannot see the routes in ngview directory

Answer (score 0):

I think the ngRoute service is missing there :

```
angular.module('AuthApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

See the doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Also, it's suppose to be templateUrl instead of template.

```js
angular.module('AuthApp',['ngRoute'])
   .config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
        .when('/about', {templateUrl:'partials/about.html'})
        .when('/dashboard', {templateUrl:'partials/dashboard.html'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home',templateUrl:'partials/home.html'})
    });
function MainCtrl($scope,$location) {
  $scope.setRoute = function(route){
    $location.path(route);
  }
}
```

Also, I don't think you should use the setRoute function. You should just set the href like that :

```
<a href="#/home" class="btn">Home</a>
```

Comment: Look at this example of ng-route, it is pretty straight-forward : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Comment: I also changed some things in my answer if you want to take a look.

Comment: And I see you're not importing angular route. <script src="angular-route.js"> (with the good path) That's the first thing to do if you read the link in my answer.

Comment: yeah i later imported that